# beautifulsoup with internal javascript

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve the rating and reviews from a website. Here is the source code I used. You can find the sample page and check the page source.

However I have a big problem, the review part is written by JavaScript code. The review is sorted by the most relevant (default), but I want the newest not the most relevant, how can I solve that?

```
url = 'http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-41-in-16-Drawer-Tool-Chest-and-Cabinet-Set-HOTC4016B1QES/205080371#customer_reviews'
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
content = preprocess_yelp_page(content) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
items = soup.findAll('span',{'itemprop':'ratingValue'})
for item in items:
    a = item.contents[0].encode('utf-8')
    indexlist.append(a)
lines = soup.findAll('span',{'itemprop':'description'})
for line in lines:
    a = line.contents[0].encode('utf-8')
    indexlist2.append(a)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the data to sort the items is *present in the page*. Just extract the data, and sort by the `datePublished` item property:

```html
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2014-11-27" />
```

The site even uses the [Schema.org microdata Review type](http://schema.org/Review) to mark up the reviews, making it extra easy for you to parse the items here.

Either look for `itemprop` attributes with BeautifulSoup, or use a tool like [rdflib-microdata](https://github.com/edsu/rdflib-microdata) to convert the information in the page to RDF, then use RDF tools to further process.

Parsing Schema.org data using BeautifulSoup:

```
reviews = []
for rating in soup.find_all(itemprop='review'):
    data = {}
    for item in rating.find_all(itemprop=True):
        data[item['itemprop']] = item.attrs.get('content') or item.get_text()
    reviews.append(data)
```

after which you can sort them by date (newest first) with:

```
reviews.sort(key=lambda i: i['datePublished'], reverse=True)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-41-in-16-Drawer-Tool-Chest-and-Cabinet-Set-HOTC4016B1QES/205080371')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
>>> reviews = []
>>> for rating in soup.find_all(itemprop='review'):
...     data = {}
...     for item in rating.find_all(itemprop=True):
...         data[item['itemprop']] = item.attrs.get('content') or item.get_text()
...     reviews.append(data)
... 
>>> reviews.sort(key=lambda i: i['datePublished'], reverse=True)
>>> pprint(reviews)
[{u'author': u'RHS381',
  u'bestRating': u'5',
  u'datePublished': u'2014-12-15',
  u'description': u' I\'ve shopped all the home improvement centers evaluating the tool box brands they carry. Including specialty stores like Sears, Harbor Freight and Northern tool. Without a doubt, HomeDepots HUSKY tool boxes and tool storage systems were a land slide winner. These box\'s are SOLID, desent gauge steel, bullet proof hardware and casters you\'d expect to find on military grade equipment. The clean finish and over all appearance was so impressed with these boxes & cabinites, that I was able to convince my wife to let me use these as our 2 year old sons bedroom furniture set. I bought 2- 46" 9 draw mobile workbenches, 2- 27" 8-draw chest and cabinet sets with 2 draw intermediate chest and 1- 41" 16 drawer tool chest and cabinet set. I don\'t know about the rest of those boxs out there that cost twice as much and are half as husky, or the men they buy them, but as for me, my son & my house, WE WILL SERVE THE HUSKY!!!!! (Pictures of completed bedroom to follow)\n',
  u'itemReviewed': u'HUSKY 41 in. 16-Drawer Tool Chest and Cabinet Set',
  u'name': u" Husky Box's as bedroom furniture\n",
  u'ratingValue': u'5',
  u'reviewRating': u'Rated 5 out of 5'},
 {u'author': u'Echristen68',
  u'bestRating': u'5',
  u'datePublished': u'2014-11-27',
  u'description': u" I've had this box for a year and it's been great for a home mechanic. I've had Craftsman cheats in the last and this is comparable as far as the steel goes. It's got some nicer features like the extra space on top with the big hinged lid. I like to organize new parts on top. This isn't a heavy duty box but it's plenty strong enough for your tools. If you organize the drawers like you should you'll never exceed the strength. The slides work smoothly but the latches are a little flimsy and can be tricky.\nThe varity of drawer sizes in nice but I would have liked to have at least one more deeper drawer for my 3/8 sockets. The large top drawer in the bottom chest is just big enough for all my 1/2 sockets.\nAll-in-all I love the look and feel. It's an OUTSTANDING value for the price vs Snap-On or even Harbor Freight boxes!\n",
  u'itemReviewed': u'HUSKY 41 in. 16-Drawer Tool Chest and Cabinet Set',
  u'name': u' I really like this box!\n',
  u'ratingValue': u'4',
  u'reviewRating': u'Rated 4 out of 5'},
 {u'author': u'Razor',
  u'bestRating': u'5',
  u'datePublished': u'2014-11-20',
  u'description': u' I spent the last month checking and looking at all tool boxes that I could find. Online and at available stores. In comparison to all, this is by far the best deal for the money. Quality, workmanship and construction of this is by far the best for the money. Some I looked at are twice as much money for the same quality... I have had this approx. a month and filled with tools and shop stuff and with the ball bearing drawers loaded, does not make any difference on drawer operation. Granted we still need the test of time..\n',
  u'itemReviewed': u'HUSKY 41 in. 16-Drawer Tool Chest and Cabinet Set',
  u'name': u' solid construction\n',
  u'ratingValue': u'5',
  u'reviewRating': u'Rated 5 out of 5'},
 {u'author': u'Skip',
  u'bestRating': u'5',
  u'datePublished': u'2014-10-28',
  u'description': u' Love the tall Top space. Drills and other rechargeable tools fit nicely up there. Drawers slide better with the more weight you put in them. Wheels rolls really well. Overall, very pleased with this box for what it cost.\n',
  u'itemReviewed': u'HUSKY 41 in. 16-Drawer Tool Chest and Cabinet Set',
  u'name': u' Nice Box for the price.\n',
  u'ratingValue': u'4',
  u'reviewRating': u'Rated 4 out of 5'},
 {u'author': u'48Kilo',
  u'bestRating': u'5',
  u'datePublished': u'2014-10-10',
  u'description': u' This unit is solid and heavy duty. Drawers and bins are strong and provide various sizes for all our tools and accessories. Very competitive pricing. Easy to assemble. Would recommend this chest and cabinet to anyone needing to get tools organized.\n',
  u'itemReviewed': u'HUSKY 41 in. 16-Drawer Tool Chest and Cabinet Set',
  u'name': u' Exactly what we needed...\n',
  u'ratingValue': u'5',
  u'reviewRating': u'Rated 5 out of 5'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But If you click the button sort by newest, the most recent record will be December 30. This solution is just sort by newest inside the page.

Comment: Okay, but can you show me how to retrieve datePublished only? I wanna save them into a list.

Comment: @plainvanilla: `[tag['content'] for tag in soup.find_all(itemprop='datePublished')]` gets you a list of all those dates.

Comment: Do you mean ?   dates = soup.findAll('itemprop':'datePublished')

Comment: @plainvanilla: no, I am using BeautifulSoup 4 syntax, and you can use `itemprop` as keyword argument.

Comment: @plainvanilla: `sorted([tag['content'] for tag in soup.find_all(itemprop='datePublished')], reverse=True)` gives me `[u'2014-12-15', u'2014-11-27', u'2014-11-20', u'2014-10-28', u'2014-10-10']` for the URL you gave.